# Stop single NLB node at command line

Tags: nlb

We have a NLB cluster set up for our public web servers. I'm trying to stop the "localhost" in the cluster from the command line using NLB.EXE. When I write "nbl stop" it seems that all nodes are stopped but I only want the local node (the server I'm running the command prompt on) to be stopped in the cluster.

When I try specifying the node using the command "nlb stop 192.168.182.104:HOSTNAME" it fails, saying "Did not receive response from the cluster".

Am I not specifying the cluster and the host correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Nodes must be part of the cluster already. "nlb start" and "nlb stop" will make the node become and active member of the cluster or an inactive member.
"nlb start <shared_cluster_ip>:<nlb_adaptor_interface>"
eg: nlb start 10.166.250.199:172.16.1.202 will start a particular node within that cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The guide at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772833(WS.10).aspx explains that simply "nlb stop" will stop all NLB functions on the localhost.